# How to center a piecewise function. (On the page.)

Tags: horizontal-alignment

Look at similar questions I can't find anything exactly what I'm looking for. I've already got the actual function aligned properly but when I compile it to a PDF, the function is centered on the page despite being within the `flushleft` environment.

Here's the code I have:

```
\begin{flushleft}

\[T(n)=
    \begin{cases}
        2 & : n = 1 \\
        T(n-1)+2 & : n \geq 1
    \end{cases}
\]

\end{flushleft}
```

How can I get this entire function aligned to the left side of the page?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Your title is misleading, in my point of view: You don't want to center your equation/function.

Comment: You are using `\[... \]` which centers and beautifies the math style. Omit them and use `\(...\)`, for example

Comment: \documentclass{article}, usepackage{amsmath}

Comment: Please add that to your example above and wrap a complete `\begin{document}...\end{document}` around your `flushleft` stuff

Comment: @ChristianHupfer That worked perfectly. :) I didn't know you could do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\[...\]` automatically centers the math content, whereas `\(...\)` (or `$...$`) doesn't center it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}

\[T(n)=
    \begin{cases}
        2 & : n = 1 \\
        T(n-1)+2 & : n \geq 1
    \end{cases}
\]


\(T(n)=
    \begin{cases}
        2 & : n = 1 \\
        T(n-1)+2 & : n \geq 1
    \end{cases}
\)


\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or just do `\noindent\(...\)` and leave the whole flush-block away.